# What does $ in R language represent?

Tags: r

What does this `$` represents in this code. Is it like a `.` function in Python or something else:

```
prices$chas <- as.factor(prices$chas)
prices$rad <- as.factor(prices$rad)
```

Comment: The `$` is documented on the `?Extract` help page. As with most operator-like things in R, it's a function.

Comment: It's a function that returns a column (by column name) of a data.frame, or a named element of a list.

Comment: Note that in contrast to other languages, `.` in R is just another character in a name; it is often used like `_`.

Comment: Hi STK, welcome to Stack Overflow. I see your question has already been downvoted a few times, and I'm guessing the main reason why is that it does not show research effort; However, with Robert's edits I think it's a pretty clear question and Quentin's answer not only addressed all the issues you raised but I think could be useful to people familiar with Python but not R (or maybe even vice-versa). I think you should go ahead and accept Quentin's answer and maybe your question will even get some up-votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prices` is a data.frame or a named list. `price$chas` allows to access the column named `chas`  in a data.frame, or the element named `chas` in a named list.

`price$chas` is the equivalent of `prices["chas"]` in python

Comment: Thank you for the help now i understood